# Android 4.4 SMS: How to insert message into SMS provider in android 4.4 by setting my app as default sms app

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I need to insert 1 message in SMS provider in 4.4 device and my app sends one time sms for login. So i don't want to see this login sms sent in default sms provider(sent items) in android 4.4 device. As per this blog [found here](http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

We have to set our app as default sms app before insert message to SMS provider or in order to  avoid inserting sent message(1 time sms used for login)to sms provider. I have used following code to set my app as default sms app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra(Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getPackageName());
startActivity(intent);
```

It is not working. Can anybody please suggest me the right approach for the above requirement.

Comment: see the changes for SMS provider from Android 4.4 here http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#Behaviors

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: I have gone through above links and tried to implement it but it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: Not working means, It is should be showing dialog(system dialog) to user for changing app as default SMS app which is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 18) {
String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(SwippSettingsActivity.this);
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "TEXT");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_DONT_KILL_APP, false);
if (defaultSmsPackageName != null) {
          sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
}
startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your manifest to include the needed receivers. Though you're not using them you need to define the receivers mentioned in that blog for the system to consider your app as a default sms candidate.